# Associating a live id with a downloaded executable

Tags: asp.net, windows-live-id

I am writing a webpage that can be used to download an executable that can run on your machine and can access System Registry on user approval. The site has live id authentication before the user can download the executable to run. This executable reads system registry for a list of installed metro apps.  The executable then uploads data from the scan to a database in the cloud. Is there a way for the executable to somehow get access to the live id that the user logged into the webpage with? I would like to upload the live-id + results of the scan to the database. The database will be keyed off the user's live id. We would need to assume that the user may not be logged on his local machine with the live id account.

Any help will be greatly appreciated, as would any other means to achieve this result.

Answer (score 0):

I’m not really sure you can easily associate this using only .exe file. You can experiment with following options

Change your app so that it can read live ID from an xml config file and then instead having users to download only exe you get them to download exe + config in a zip file for example.

Second option is to have the user to manually enter live ID before running the app.

Another option would be to match MAC address used to access the application with MAC address used to send the results. When user logs in you store it’s MAC address somewhere and then match that with MAC address used for sending data. Not an ideal solution really but you can work on something similar in this direction.